# SVG ShowContextMenu event not working from an embedded SVG image

Tags: javascript, svg

I have an HTML page with an SVG image on it. Within the SVG image is another SVG image.

The code below shows an extract from the SVG image that is on the HMTL page.

```
<image x="100" y="80" width="250px" height="300px" xlink:href="TestModule-Basic.svg" onclick="moduleSelected('Test Expanded')" />

<g id="p21" transform="translate(50, 175)" visibility="inherit" class="General" oncontextmenu="ShowContextMenu(event, this)">

</g>
```

Within the TestModule-Basic.svg is a group exactly the same as the group id=21. shown above.

Each SVG image has a function (in the SVG file) for ShowContextMenu(..., ....) and for this test it just prints to the console.

The problem I have is that the function doesn't get called from within the TestModule-Basic event. However it does get called from the other svg file.

When you add an svg image to another svg image do the events still work? How can I make them work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: javascript does not run in `<image>` elements. If you want javascript to run you'd need to use an `<iframe>` or `<object>` tag.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you have an example. I have tried to use object and iframe but the image doesn't display. I know they work when used in the HTML but do these work from within an SVG image?

Comment: You need to use `<iframe>` and `<object>` on the html page. within the SVG image you'd have to inline the SVG data or include it using `<foreignObject>` and then `<iframe>` or `<object>`